# Finding first non-digit character with .find in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string containing containing `ABC 12345` but also `ABC 98765.` or `ABC 55555<`

For finding `ABC` and then identifying the following sequence of numbers I use

```
index = page.find('ABC',index)
t1 = page.find(' ',index+1)
t2 = page.find(' ',t1+4)
```

This gives me `12345` as a result, but not `98765` or `55555`.

How do I have to alter line 3 to find spaces and other characters like `.` or `<`?

I tried

```
import re

t2 = re.search("\d", page,t1+4)
```

but this syntax is broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use regular expressions to find numbers that follow the literal text `ABC` plus optional whitespace:

```
match = re.search(r'ABC\s*(\d+)', page)
if match:
    print match.group(1)
```

This works regardless of what follows the digits:

```
>>> re.search(r'ABC\s*(\d+)', 'ABC 98765.').group(1)
'98765'
>>> re.search(r'ABC\s*(\d+)', 'ABC 55555<').group(1)
'55555'
```

If you need to find multiple matches, use `findall()` instead:

```
matches = re.findall(r'ABC\s*(\d+)', page)
```

which gives you a list of all digit groups that follow the literal text `ABC`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'ABC\s*(\d+)', 'Some text with ABC 98765. There is some other text too, with ABC 55555<!')
['98765', '55555']
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It is so much simpler, much better code (even from a newbie’s perspective). It takes significantly longer than my solution (with wrong results), can I speed up this?

Comment: @lejonet8: Sorry, what takes longer? The regular expression?

Comment: Yes, running the script with regular expressions.

Comment: How large is your input? We could make the `\s*` non-greedy, replace it with `\s*?` or even just `ABC (\d+)` to match only *one* space.

Comment: 85 kb. Switching to `(\d+)` solved these performance issues. Thank you again, your help is highly appreciated.